# Can't reset Windows 7 Registry permissions

Tags: windows-7, access-control-list

I am trying to reset win 7 registry permissions using

```
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose /areas REGKEYS
```

But i am receiving the following error:

```
An extended error has occurred. The task has completed with an error.
See log %windir%\security\logs\scesrv.log for detail info.
```

The content Of the log file

```
------------------------------------------- Friday, April 16, 2010 1:50:43 PM
----Configuration engine was initialized successfully.---- 
----Reading Configuration Template info...

----Configure 64-bit Registry Keys...   
Configure users\.default.
Warning 5: Access is denied. Error taking ownership of
           users\.default\software\SetID.
Warning 5: Access is denied. Error opening users\.default\software\SetID.
Warning 5: Access is denied. Error setting security on
           users\.default\software\SetID.
Configure machine\software.
Warning    5: Access is denied. Error setting security on machine\software.
Warning 1336: The access control list (ACL) structure is invalid. Error setting
              security on machine\software\Macrovision.
Configuration of Registry Keys was completed with one or more errors.

----Configure 32-bit Registry Keys...
Configure machine\software.
Warning 1336: The access control list (ACL) structure is invalid. Error setting
              security on machine\software\Audible.
Configuration of Registry Keys was completed with one or more errors.

----Un-initialize configuration engine...
```